# How to force Swift iOS game application to open up in landscape orientation? (GameViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I am creating a game in iOS with Spritekit and I want my game to be in landscape orientation only. However every time I test my game in the simulator it always loads up in portrait orientation no matter what I try. I have read many stack overflow post on this issue and I have tried the following with no success:

GameViewController

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft]
}
```

Please note I have also tried switching Autorotate from true to false. This did not work either.

Xcode project file

[Xcode project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSTge.png)

Info.plist

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1TTY.png)

None of this has worked

Comment: What's your Xcode version?  If you are using Xcode 8.3.x under macOS X 10.2.x, there might be a bug.

Comment: @ElTomato Xcode 9 beta Swift 4

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this function:

```
func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

Comment: I want it in landscape

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` for setting up orientation.

```
 private var orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        get { return self.orientations }
        set { self.orientations = newValue }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Comment: What do I put for newValue

Comment: @StevenCassidy newValue is landscapeLeft which is already defined, i edited answer. Try this code it will work :)

Comment: Which file do I put this in my view controller or My scene

Comment: @StevenCassidy whichever is first in your case !!

Comment: The simulator is still loading up in portrait  where can I post the code for my view controller